# How to write recursive left-shift array algorithm more efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm

I was completing some practice problems today on HackerRank, and on a problem asking me to write an algorithm that left-shifts all elements in an array n-times (i.e. rotLeft({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 1) returns {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}), I ran into the classic timeout error due to my algorithm being inefficient. This isn't the first time I have been dinged for inefficient algo writing by an online coding system. Really I have two questions: 1) How can I specifically rewrite my left-shift algorithm to be more time-efficient? 2) In general, how do I improve performance-wise upon an algorithm which runs inefficiently?

```
public static final int NULL = -2147483648;

static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    return rotLeftRec(a, d, 0);
}
static int[] rotLeftRec(int[] a, int d, int numRot) {
    if (numRot >= d) {
        return a;
    } else {
        int first = a[0];
        int temp1 = NULL;
        int temp2 = NULL;
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i == a.length - 1) {
                temp1 = a[i];
            } else {
                if (temp1 == NULL) {
                    temp1 = a[i];
                    a[i] = temp2;
                    temp2 = NULL;
                } else {
                    temp2 = a[i];
                    a[i] = temp1;
                    temp1 = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        a[a.length - 1] = first;
    }
    return rotLeftRec(a, d, numRot + 1);
}
```

Comment: I would remove the "general" part 2 of your question, too broad for SO imo.

Comment: It must be recursive? I mean, it is not a recursive problem as such. I'm thinking about System.arraycopy, that should speed up things quite a bit.

Comment: The Best way you can optimize your code is to have a pre calculated shifted array. i.e., for your example, rotate by 1 and rotate by 6 should give same answer, the number of different arrays you can have is the number of elements in the array. So for any input you can simply do shifts%n, where n is number of elements in array and shifts is the number of shifts you need to do. this way your algorithm complexity will be O(n), if you shift arrays for n times or O(1) time, O(N) memory if you maintain pre-calculated arrays, to avoid recalculation.

Comment: Instead of rotating the _entire array_ one step _N_ times, move the elements directly to their correct final positions  _N_ steps to the left in one pass. That's _N_ times faster.  And using `System.arraycopy` to move a block of elements will probably be faster than using a programmed move-one-character-at-a-time loop to move the same block.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Also thank you for explaining the way System.arraycopy 's use in this specific case. One char at a time is slowing down the algo significantly; that makes a lot more sense for me to copy all at once

Comment: @ram914 Thanks for the time complexity explanation! I'll try this as well: if (n > array.length) { n %= array.length; } so I don't repeat calculations

Comment: And don't forget that if `n == 0` (after n %= array.length), you don't have to do anything at all!  It would be just like those jokers at HackerRank to give you a million-element array and tell you to rotate it two million times just to trap the unwary...

Comment: given a deque, one could concatenate it to itself. then upon rotation, just keep the interesting slice!

Comment: @KevinAnderson LOL I just used 5 hackos to see one of the two test cases that was giving a runtime error and it was EXACTLY this. Literally downloaded a 2GB test case that was inputting n = array.length

Comment: what if you append same array in the end and start printing n array elements from kth (0 based indexing) index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious about the arraycopy approach, looks like this. There's no need to call the method proposed here m times where you shift the array by n each time. You can call it with the product m*n and you're there as well (I think). Would be curious if that one passes.

Btw. ArrayList uses arrayCopy, I got it from there.

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    if (d < 0 || a == null || a.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int shift = d % a.length;
    if (shift == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    int[] result = new int[a.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, shift, result, 0, a.length - shift);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, a.length - shift, shift);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You recurse for `d` times shifting once. That is inefficient as you can immediately find the correct value at index `i` by `i+d % a.length`.

The point is left-rotating by `d` would seem to need multiple variables. For *this* you should use recursion.

```
static void rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    rotLeftRec(a, d, 0);
}

static void rotLeftRec(int[] a, int d, int i) {
    if (i >= a.length) {
        return;
    }
    int j = (i + d) % a.length;
    int aj = a[j];
    rotLeftRec(a, d, i + 1);
    a[i] = aj;
}
```

The trick is, that **after** coming back from the recursion you fill in the data `a[i]` with the value of `a[j]` you remembered **before** the recursive call.

You see, that the recursion enables you to hold a stack of `i` and `aj`.

Implementing such recursion is doing the simple step and looking at the time line of variables, what should be remembered beforehand, what future partial result is needed (some return value of a recursive call).

---

***Transformation to iterative version*** (still further optimizable)

```
static void rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    int[] stack = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        int j = (i + d) % a.length;
        int aj = a[j];
        stack[i] = aj;
    }
    System.arraycopy(stack, 0, a, 0, a.length);
}
```

Comment: am curious how the versions compare runtime wise

Comment: @curiosa Instead originally `d * array.length` (recursion * iteration) it is just `array.length` (recursion). As maximal d = array.length - 1, average d = array.length/2, it is **quadratic** against **linear** complexity wrt. to the array size.

Comment: yeah, I mean the arraycopy version vs recursion done this way, the latter looking much more subtle of course.

Comment: @curiosa Both actually do the same, O(N), though arraycopy is very fast with the cost of an array creation. However my recursion stores the old array elements on the stack. One could optimize that by comparing `i` and `j`, to see whether `a[i]` can be filled earlier. And some even more uglifying optimization. By the way for in-situ changing `a` you could use an array of d elements.

Comment: @Joop Eggen The first time I rewrote my solution I went this route; however, as curiosa noticed the recursion algo performs nowhere near as well as System.arraycopy, which was why I was failing 2 tests on hackerrank due to runtime

Comment: One can easily transform the recursion above to an iterative version using an array (stack). Your chosen answer is fine; I wanted to point out to recurse not wildly. I'll add the transformation.